# Show that the limit of the integral of this continuous function exists

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Given a continuous function $\,\mathrm{f}:\left[0,1\right] \to \mathbb{R}$,
I have been asked to show
$$
\lim\limits_{a \downarrow  0}\int_{a}^{1} t^{-2/3}\,\,\mathrm{f}\left(t\right)\,  \mathrm{d}t
$$
exists, but I'm having a lot of difficulty. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with the (generalised) mean value theorem for integrals? I have not tested it myself, but that would be my go.

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, so I'm no sure if I'd be allowed to use. But I'll have a look at it.

Comment: You can probably use that f(t) is bounded on this closed interval. So, |f(t)|<=M where M is some constant. You know this, because it is a continuous function on a closed interval. Then you only have to do the same problem for the integral without the f(t) part. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let  $f^+:=\max(f,0)$ and $f^-:=\max(-f,0)$, then $f=f^+-f^-$.
Define
$$I_+(a)=\int_a^1t^{-2/3}f^+(t) dt\quad\mbox{and} \quad I_-(a)=\int_a^1t^{-2/3}f^-(t) dt.$$
The functions $I_+$ and $I_-$ in $(0,1]$ are non-negative, decreasing (the integrands are non negative), and bounded above by
$$M\int_0^{1}t^{-2/3}dt=M[3t^{1/3}[_0^1=3M$$
where $M=\max_{[0,1]} |f(x)|$.
This implies that their limits as $a\to 0^+$ exist: 
$$\lim_{a\to 0^+}I_+(a)=\sup_{a\in[0,1]}I_+(a)
\quad\mbox{and} \quad
\lim_{a\to 0^+}I_-(a)=\sup_{a\in[0,1]}I_-(a).$$
Hence also the required limit exists,
$$\lim_{a\to 0^+}\int _a ^1  t^{-2/3} f(t)  dt
=\sup_{a\in[0,1]}I_+(a)-\sup_{a\in[0,1]}I_-(a).$$

Comment: @Jonahhill Any further doubt?

Comment: That's great! Thank you so much!